# Unfortunately, (application name) has stopped

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am new to android, I am trying to make game in android. In that game I have to draw canvas, I followed a tutorial to learn "How to draw canvas in android". In that tutorial he is using two classes named as GFX and Main, he is not showing any XML file, so I am using its default XML which is populated by eclipse editor automatically.

I have followed the tutorial, but when I try to run that application on my device a message appears on my device screen, **Unfortunately,Seven has stopped.** "Seven" is my application name.
"blackball" is name of a image which I want to display on screen. I have saved this image in my res/drawable-hdpi folder.
Following is the code, I am adding both classes, default XML file and Logcat.
GFX File.

```
package com.example.seven;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GFX extends Activity
{
 Main objec;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     objec=new Main(this);
     setContentView(objec);
 }
}
```

Main

```
package com.example.seven;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
public class Main extends View
{
    Bitmap blackdot;
    public Main(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        blackdot= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blackball);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawBitmap(blackdot, (canvas.getWidth())/2, 0, null);

    }
    }
```

XML File

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".Main" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Below is the Logcat output**

```
03-11 12:26:13.968: D/dalvikvm(8248): newInstance failed: no <init>()
03-11 12:26:13.968: D/AndroidRuntime(8248): Shutting down VM
03-11 12:26:13.968: W/dalvikvm(8248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40eca258)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.seven/com.example.seven.Main}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.seven.Main; no empty constructor
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.seven.Main; no empty constructor
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-11 12:26:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):     ... 11 more
```

Here is manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seven"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.seven.GFX"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GFX" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: At which line you got error? what error??

Comment: when I run this code on my device. A message appears in black background "Unfortunately, application has stopped."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.seven.Main; no empty constructor
```

This exception with the hint in stacktrace that the framework was trying to instantiate your activity explains the issue: You have listed your `Main` class as an activity in the manifest. The class is not an `Activity`, though the instantiation fails earlier to missing empty constructor (since you've overridden the constructor) and not later when the created object was cast to an `Activity`.

Seems like `GFX` is your main activity.

To fix it, change `Main` activity from manifest to `GFX`.

In your edited question, keep the `action` as `MAIN` here:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.GFX" />
```

Change to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

It's there to specify the main entry point of your app and the name has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: I tried this, and following error occurred in console.

Comment: [2014-03-11 12:46:08 - Seven] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.seven/.Main }
[2014-03-11 12:46:08 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2014-03-11 12:46:08 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.seven/com.example.seven.Main} does not exist.

Comment: It's still trying to launch the `Main` class specified in the manifest. Just edit the manifest, changing the `activity` there.

Comment: I have changed Main to GFX in manifest. Still nothing changed.

Comment: Edit the question and add your manifest there so we can better help you with that.

Comment: Now when I run this application, nothing appears on screen and following error appears on console.

Comment: [2014-03-11 13:00:38 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2014-03-11 13:00:38 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.seven/com.example.seven.Main} does not exist.

Comment: I have included Manifest file now.

Comment: After changing nothing happened on device screen, below is the console output.

Comment: [2014-03-11 14:08:29 - Seven] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.seven/.Main }
[2014-03-11 14:08:29 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2014-03-11 14:08:29 - Seven] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.seven/com.example.seven.Main} does not exist.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the app, seems like definitions from an older versions are used.

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the default empty constructor. Actually you don't need to pass the context explicitly here. Activity itself is a subclass of context. And you can always use `getApplicationContext()` in an activity. So change your the constructor to `pulic Main()` would help you resolve the issue.
EDIT: Just realized that its a view you're using. So to get context for a view, You can call `getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error in your CustomView's Constructor class ,resolve it like this

```
 private static Context mContext;
     public Main(Context context) {
         this.mContext = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        blackdot= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blackball);
    }
```